# What's the quickest and most effective way of removing food from the windpipe in an emergency room setting?

Tags: choking, emergency-room, heimlich-maneuver, trachea-windpipe

The Heimlich maneuver is well-known as a way of ejecting food and other obstructions from the windpipe, yet it is not always effective. If someone began choking on food in the best possible environment, *in an emergency room* or even *on an operating table*, with no particular choice of food for this question, what would be the best alternative to the Heimlich maneuver to clear it?